# C++ templates' need for an empty constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I am puzzled as to why this is needed or if I have got something else wrong which is causing my problem.

I have some template based code...

```
template <typename T>
     class redblacknode{

private:
    T value;    
public:
    int colour;
    redblacknode* up;
    redblacknode* left;
    redblacknode* right;
    redblacknode(T& v);
    redblacknode(redblacknode* node);
    redblacknode(redblacknode& node);
    redblacknode* grandparent() const;
    redblacknode* uncle() const;
    redblacknode* sibling() const;
    T& getvalue();
    bool bothchildrenblack() const;
    bool equals(redblacknode*) const;
    bool lessthan(redblacknode*) const;
    void assign(redblacknode*);
    void showinorder(redblacknode*) const;
    void showpreorder(redblacknode*) const;
    void showpostorder(redblacknode*) const;
};
```

The puzzling thing is that if I declare a class I want to use in this like this...

```
class pagechain{

....
pagechain(long page);
....

};

pagechain::pagechain(long page)
{
  pagenumber = page;
}

....

pagechain dummy = pagechain(initialvalue);
redblacknode<pagechain>(dummy);
```

This code fails - saying I need to explicitly initialise T

```
./redblack.hpp:31:3: error: constructor for 'redblacknode<pagechain>' must explicitly initialize the member 'value' which does not have a default constructor
            redblacknode(T& v);
```

But I add a dumb constructor to pagechain...

```
pagechain(){};
```

The code compiles... what causes this behaviour/what have I got wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I can't see the code for your constructor `redblacknode(T& v)`, I'm guessing it looks something like the following:

```
template <typename T> redblacknode<T>::redblacknode(T& v) {
    value = v;
}
```

What this is doing is calling `T`'s default constructor, then assigning it the value of `v`. What you want to do instead is to use an initializer statement:

```
template <typename T> redblacknode<T>::redblacknode(T& v) 
    : value(v)
{
}
```

This way you don't need to default-construct `value`, as `value` is now constructed in one step, instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you to explicitly initialize `value` (not T), read the error message exactly.

If you declare a member variable

```
 T value;
```

the compiler wants to generate initialization code for the variable "value" as part of any constructor of `redblacknode`. This works automatically when `T` has a ctor without parameters. If there is no such ctor (and when do don't provide one, there is none for `pagechain`, since you have added a ctor *with* a parameter, which disables the auto generated parameterless ctor), you can instead provide an explicit initialization like

```
public redblacknode::redblacknode(T& v)
  :value(0)
{
}
```

(you have to implement all `redblacknode` constructors that way).